# How can I see all the comments with the Youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a problem in Youtube API Comments.

When i access http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-12_0ZP2p4g/comments , he not show all comments in the video...

This is a problem for me, cause i need ALL information and comments.

When i access the video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-12_0ZP2p4g ), i found comments that are not on API.

Anybody know why this happens?

Tnks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are currently using the 2.0 API, this API is deprecated now.

Anyway, to achieve what you want - with the 2.0 API - you have to implement some sort of pagination to move through the results.

If you parse what is returned you will get come across a `<link>` tag with `rel='next'` it's recommend that you use that link (the `href` attribute) to avoid pagination problems.

For more information check out : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#Paging_through_Results

Comment: Hey Noctrine
Tnks for your help..
I find the error...

You recommended using 3.0 API, but, this API dont return the video's comments...right?
Again, tnks...