# No replies or not all comments retrieved using Google YouTube V3 API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve all comments to a video with all replies, however, using the Test It interface (or the Java library) I have not been able to retrieve all comments - I have following two examples, when I have failed:

## Example 1

The example video and comment is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCLy2DZdXhY&lc=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04 
When I retrieve the comment using

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&id=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I receive:
[image: The response for the particular comment - note that there are 2 replies]

And note the `"totalReplyCount": 2,` line.

However, when I try to obtain all replies using the parentId:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I receive an empty response:

[image: Empty response]

### Remarks

I have read [Youtube Data API v3: commentThread call doesn't give replies for some comment threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546995/youtube-data-api-v3-commentthread-call-doesnt-give-replies-for-some-comment-th) , however, it does not provide me the answer as I do use the comments list with parentId and I am still not getting any replies.

Even if I try the not recommended way - using the part `snippet,replies`, I do not get any replies:
Request:
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&id=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[image: Still no replies]

However, if I do not specify the comment thread by its ID and specify that I want all comment threads for the video:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId=xCLy2DZdXhY&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then voila - The comment thread is now with those two replies:

[image: Now with replies - Part 1]
[image: Now with replies - Part 2]

Why do I receive the replies now and not when I either specify the replies by their parentId or when I specify the comment thread by its id?

Moreover, if I take the (weird) id of one of the replies and try to obtain the comment with this reply, I will receive empty response:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&id=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04.1443381718685326&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[image: Cannot find the reply]

## Example 2

This problem is a bit different.
I have a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c76GeR2IWg with 7 comments (6 of them are top levels). When I try to obtain all top level comments related to this video I receive only 4 of them.
     GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId=-c76GeR2IWg&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[image: Only 4 top level comments]

One of the missing comments in the response is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c76GeR2IWg&lc=z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k .
When I train to obtain comment thread with this id, I do obtain the comment thread:
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&id=z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[image: I can find it using its id]

And also, when I try to obtain the replies for this comment (there should be 1 reply) I receive an empty response:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[image]

## Remarks

- For both examples, the number of comments is less than the size of the page. For this simple example, I have skipped pagination and chose examples with only a few comments, in the real application I use the pagination but I do not get more results.
- I do not really understand how is the YouTube and G+ integrated together, thus this might be the issue, however, I was always accesing these videos using only youtube, not checking the users' G+ page, thus I would say that this should not be the case.

## Similar questions on SO:

- [How can I see all the comments with the Youtube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552101/how-can-i-see-all-the-comments-with-the-youtube-api) This is about V2 API, thus no use for me.
- [Youtube Data API v3: commentThread call doesn't give replies for some comment threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546995/youtube-data-api-v3-commentthread-call-doesnt-give-replies-for-some-comment-th) This question is very similar and raises similar problems, however, it is exactly the other way around - The author does not receive all replies using the commentThread replies (which is agreeing with the documentation), however, the proposed solution is "Use the  [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list)call instead and specify the commentThread's ID for the parentId." - which is exactly what does not work for me.
- [YouTube Data API v3 Comment Thread Discrepency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974742/youtube-data-api-v3-comment-thread-discrepency) The author forgot about pagination.
- [YouTube Data API v3 - Comment threads request doesn't return all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399772/youtube-data-api-v3-comment-threads-request-doesnt-return-all-comments) Similar question, yet without any answer.

Comment: The API seems to be not working. It is an error from Google's side.

Answer (score 1):

When I do the following via HTTP request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I get the following response:

```
items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#comment",
   "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/aOipn7OKd9ibVua9TWdtD2vJJgI\"",
   "id": "z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04.1443381718685326",
   "snippet": {
    "textDisplay": "JM",
    "parentId": "z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04",
    "authorDisplayName": "Asia Price",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtUuxM3_g2hWA7qr17d85RQ",
    "authorChannelId": {
     "value": "UCtUuxM3_g2hWA7qr17d85RQ"
    },
    "authorGoogleplusProfileUrl": "https://plus.google.com/100662746258967935686",
    "canRate": false,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "publishedAt": "2015-09-27T19:21:58.685Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-27T19:21:58.685Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#comment",
   "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/NtowtHGdhytzw9YY9RxUopEgoTA\"",
   "id": "z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04.1443365800258222",
   "snippet": {
    "textDisplay": "0",
    "parentId": "z12ei1s5gs2mc303523qsdigcxmphhlrd04",
    "authorDisplayName": "FAY Fay",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5b4dTxK4ae_roaMWMYpglQ",
    "authorChannelId": {
     "value": "UC5b4dTxK4ae_roaMWMYpglQ"
    },
    "authorGoogleplusProfileUrl": "https://plus.google.com/100517618639903741268",
    "canRate": false,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "publishedAt": "2015-09-27T14:56:40.258Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-27T14:56:40.258Z"
   }
  }
```

I get the same results when I use the API explorer.

For your second example,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

gives me

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#comment",
   "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/UBoqDwv8bg8xZpbIepzI_M5gp9o\"",
   "id": "z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k.1409319325542384",
   "snippet": {
    "textDisplay": "Ahoj děkuju :) jo máš fajn videa :) ",
    "parentId": "z120d11g2yyjyxcxw04cg1xbaqfnslfaamk0k",
    "authorDisplayName": "Gumičkování s Péťou",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-VJce_PtJx70/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABI/dabMtsy0haY/photo.jpg?sz=50",
    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAyuADHtiVTpiAbt2VVQhtQ",
    "authorChannelId": {
     "value": "UCAyuADHtiVTpiAbt2VVQhtQ"
    },
    "authorGoogleplusProfileUrl": "https://plus.google.com/101894467260220798842",
    "canRate": false,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "publishedAt": "2014-08-29T13:35:25.542Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-08-29T13:35:25.542Z"
   }
  }
```

It might be an issue with your request or API key. Try making a new one and using that.

Comment: Interesting. I produced the examples above using the Try me function on the documentation page, thus I have not use the API key as I used in the actual application (where it did produce same results).  However, I had still the form filled in a tab, thus I was able to replicate exactly the same request as I used for producing these examples - and weirdly, i got different results - it is working now, but I am sure I did not change anything (and another user was able to replicate my results at the time of my question). Thus It might have been just a temporal thing.

Comment: I will wait a while and try it again several times to see whether the error will appear again - if not I will just close the question. However, I have tried all the request I have filled from the previous time and they seem to miraculously work now - thus it indeed seems to be a temporal glitch (is that possible?)

Comment: Not sure, but hopefully you won't be seeing the issue again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, I have a small follow up question: why does the pageInfo field sometimes contain the totalResults and sometimes it does not?

Comment: I know there was a previous issue where totalResults wouldn't show up (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488713/youtube-data-api-v3-comment-threads-request-doesnt-return-count-of-total-resu)) and it seemed like it was fixed and working correctly (for awhile). But I wouldn't be surprised if it's still slightly buggy.

Comment: Well, it seems it is still buggy - I sometimes receive only "resultsPerPage": 20 and not totalResults.