# I can't get replies with Youtube API comment:list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get all replies to a specific comment with Youtube API. 
Like this:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=***&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

But I always get blank even after I checked in the commentThreads that the totalReplyCount is not 0.

It worked perfectly 3 days before, and I tried with a new API key, didn't work either.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your attention.

11/19
I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433116/no-replies-or-not-all-comments-retrieved-using-google-youtube-v3-api). But there is no definite answer and his code is maliciously working again. So I thought it was a temporal thing, but its been 3 days and mine is still not working.