# Retrieve Youtube Comment Replies

Tags: youtube-api, comments

I am trying to extract comments from youtube videos. I am able to retrieve the comments (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#try-it) but I am not able to identify how to retrieve the replies of the individual comments. I looked at the Youtube API documentation but can not exactly pinpoint how to retrieve the comment replies. Can anyone let me know if it is even possible? If yes, how do I do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list), you can use the `parentId` parameter which specifies the ID of the comment for which replies should be retrieved. But be noted that YouTube currently supports replies only for top-level comments and replies to replies may be supported in the future. You can use `comments.list` method retrieve comment replies.

Example:

```
//Call the YouTube Data API's comments.list method  to retrieve existing comment replies.

V3CommentListResponse commentsListResponse = youtube.comments().list("snippet")
         .setParentId(parentId).setTextFormat("plainText").execute();
List<Comment> comments = commentsListResponse.getItems();

if (comments.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Can't get comment replies.");
} else {
    // Print information from the API response.
    System.out.println("\n===========Returned Comment Replies============\n");  

    for (Comment commentReply : comments) {
         snippet = commentReply.getSnippet();
         System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
         System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
         System.out.println("\n---------------\n");
    }

    Comment firstCommentReply = comments.get(0);
    firstCommentReply.getSnippet().setTextOriginal("updated");
    Comment commentUpdateResponse = youtube.comments()
            .update("snippet", firstCommentReply).execute();
    // Print information from the API response.
    System.out.println("\n============Updated Video Comment===============\n");
         snippet = commentUpdateResponse.getSnippet();
         System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
         System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
         System.out.println("\n--------------------------------\n");
```

Check on this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433116/no-replies-or-not-all-comments-retrieved-using-google-youtube-v3-api).

Answer (score 0):

According the [API Documentation of YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), you can retrieve comments and related replies by adding parameter `part` with value `snippet,replies` to the `commentThreads` endpoint, like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY]
```

The example above includes the video ID and API key.